# My database connection uses a background context, what context should my cursor use for aggregate queries? TODO()?

Tags: mongodb, go

I have a standard mongo db connection that is initialised using the official Go driver (mongo-go-driver)

The context for this db connection and the connection details are:

```
setContext = context.Background()

mongoURI := fmt.Sprintf("mongodb://%s:%s@%s/?authSource=admin", mongoUser, mongoPwd, mongoAddress)

mongoContext, cancel := context.WithTimeout(setContext, 5*time.Second)

clientOptions := options.Client().ApplyURI(mongoURI).SetMaxPoolSize(50)

defer cancel()

mongoSession, err := mongo.Connect(mongoContext, clientOptions)
```

From the documentation, https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/context  I understand that this is correct:

> Background returns a non-nil, empty Context. It is never canceled, has no values, and has no deadline. It is typically used by the main function, initialization, and tests, and as the top-level Context for incoming requests.

Now, when running my queries against this connection, what context should I be using?

Here's an example of using the connection:

```
mongoConnection := myMongoSessionOfficialDriver.Database(db).Collection(collection)

pipeOptions := options.Aggregate().SetMaxTime(time.Second * 10)

mongoCursor, err := mongoConnection.Aggregate(context.TODO(), aggregationPipeline, pipeOptions)
```

My question is this: **what should the context be for the cursor?!** Should it be background() i'm thinking not if it should be cancelled (when my query returns the data)

In the documentation, for TODO() it says:

> TODO returns a non-nil, empty Context. Code should use context.TODO when it's unclear which Context to use or it is not yet available (because the surrounding function has not yet been extended to accept a Context parameter). TODO is recognized by static analysis tools that determine whether Contexts are propagated correctly in a program.

**Okay... well what context should I be using for aggregate queries?**

Comment: `Background` and `TODO` are exactly the same, and neither do anything special.

Comment: Hmmm how do you know that? That isn't clear from the context documentation. Also, do you know if I should even be using the background/TODO context in my... context?

Comment: Besides that the documentations states it, you can look at the source: https://golang.org/src/context/context.go#L197. You need _a_ context, so you have to start somewhere. If you don't have a context, the only root contexts are from `Background` or `TODO`.

Comment: `TODO` is intended as a placeholder for cases where you later intend to pass a "real" context but you don't have one to use yet. If you just need a context with no intention of cancelling, use `Background`. That's a purely semantic difference though, they have no functional difference.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation with these, what context would you recommend for the aggregate queries though? The context should be cancelled when the read operation is completed

Comment: Follow what the documentation says. If you're planning on threading in a parent context in the future, and want to look for calls to `context.TODO`, then use it. If you're not, then don't use it.